Hashicorp Go Plugins Not Deleting/Cleaning Up Socket Files When SIGTERM Is Sent
Apologies if this isn't the right place to post it, I wasn't sure if this question was meant to be posted here or on Superuser.
I’m using Go Plugin System over RPC as part of a service that I’m developing.
The service (irrelevant detail but developed in Golang) is managed by systemd. This leads to the creation of temporary socket files as a result of a RPC connection established for each plugin. While these socket files do get cleaned up when the service is launched outside of systemd i.e. the binary behind this service is launched manually, with systemd however when I run systemctl stop <service_name> these socket files aren’t being cleaned up leading to an accumulation over time.
Has anyone reported of such an issue ? Are there any workarounds or am I just developing it wrong ?
I'm suspecting it has to do with the SIGTERM signal that gets sent when we run systemctl stop <service_name>
I can share my code snippet if needed but before going through the hassle of redacting parts of it I wanted to just know upfront if this is even an issue or I'm doing things wrong.
